# Clearing memory from variables?

Tags: c++, box2d

So, I've heard of the `delete` keyword, which clears variables that use the `new` or `new[]` keywords.

I have a class called `Box`, which I made a object of in my `main.cpp`.

What if I want to clear a variables memory in my `Box` object, from my `main.cpp`?

I've tried adding the `new` keyword to the variables, but the variable types has no default constructor so I can't use it on them :

```
b2Body* body = new b2Body;
```

Is there any way to clear the memory of a variable that looks like this :

```
b2Body* body = nullptr;
```

(note that when I want to clear it, it has assigned a value to it.)

---

Example : 
In minecraft when an item is dropped on the ground, and it disappears after some time, I'm guessing it's texture variables, animations, stats etc is not saved?

This is what I want to do.

I want to remove the memory of a variable I no longer need to use.

Comment: In C++ you should use `delete` rather than `free()`

Comment: First of all: if you use `new` operator for allocation you must use `delete` for deallocation. Memory from `new` and `malloc` is incompatible. Second the ampersands (e,g, `free(&boxShape);`) look wrong - it seems like you are trying to delete non-pointer member. And lastly, why dont you use desctructor?

Comment: @wondra I do not use the "new" operator for anything yet. And I'm not sure how to use a de-constructor yet. :P

Comment: @tkausl So, I replaced all the free things with delete instead. Example : delete &sfmlShape; But the game still triggers a breakpoint. Error : HEAP[SFML_Game.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00700000, 00506518 )

Comment: The point of my comment was "you cant `delete` what you did not `new`ed". Before deleting something make sure it is a valid pointer to heap-allocated memory. And taking *address of* something does not make it heap-allocated memory.

Comment: @wondra What if I want to remove this variable : std::string aString = "Hello"; How would I do that? I will do some reading about heap-allocated pointer things.

Comment: This aString was allocated on stack. C++ uses [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), it will be destroyed automatically when it leaves its scope (generally to first closing curly brackets). Also this is turning in general-programming chat, you should ask these on stackoverflow or even better, seeing you dont know basic concepts yet, read some tutorials/resources/books about C++.

Comment: @wondra Tried to search what you told me on google, but still couldn't understand. I updated the question instead, still not sure if it should be here or on stackoverflow.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19344043/2672235

Comment: If you never use `new` or `malloc` then you should never use `delete` or `free`. For every `new` you use `delete` (exactly once) and the same for malloc/free, however, everything you instantiate on another way will automatically be deleted when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @tkausl What if it's inside a while loop, then it will never clear the memory until the loop is done, right? So, if i remove a object in the game (maybe a item or something) I of course want to clear it from the memory too. I'm so bad at explaining x)

Comment: Seems like you should start with some basic C++ tutorials. Or perhaps read a good programming book first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @glampert Ok, will check it out :)

Comment: If it's inside a while-loop then it will allocate and deallocate it at _every_ run through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A great tutorial on constructors and destructors in C++ is [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm).

Summary:

```
//Constructor uses binary scope operator on itself but with parameters
ExampleClass::ExampleClass(void) {
    std::cout << "Creating example class!" << std::endl;
}

//Destructor also has parameters with binary scope operator but it's an alternate version.
//This version uses the '~' character after the operator to signify that it's a destructor.
ExampleClass::~ExampleClass(void) {
        std::cout << "Destroying example class!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @BiiX No problem :)